# What is Laravel's storage and when and why should I use it?

Tags: php, laravel

What is Laravel's storage and when and why should I use it?

I know it's there but I don't know when I should by using it or why, slight newbie question. Sorry!

Comment: You asking about storage such as cache , sessions or about the `laravel_storage()` ?

Comment: Not sure, cache and laravel_storage() I guess

Comment: it's just a folder you can use it or not. i don't use it at all. i store my sessions in the database, i cache on elastic cache and store files and images on an amazon bucket.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel's Storage `storage_path()` can be found inside the `app` folder, there you can find

```
cache
logs
meta
sessions
views
```

Where your temporary data will be stored here.

As i am not sure about which storage the questioner asking i about i am telling about the session and cache too

Syntax for session :

To create a session

`Session::put('key', 'value');` and to get the value back use

`$value = Session::get('key');`

To see all the session `$data = Session::all();`

To remove the session `Session::forget('key');`

To remove all session `Session::flush();`

A session is a way to store information (in variables) to be used across multiple pages. Unlike a cookie, the information is not stored on the users computer

Here you can find [more about laravel session](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/session)

A cookie is often used to identify a user. A cookie is a small file that the server embeds on the user's computer. Each time the same computer requests a page with a browser, it will send the cookie too. With PHP, you can both create and retrieve cookie values.

And for cookie

```
$value = Cookie::get('name');
```

Find more about [laravel cookies here](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/requests#cookies)